# How do I programatically detect if my laptop is plugged in or not? (osx)

Tags: macos, shell

Exactly as the title says -- I'm looking for a way, in OSX, to tell me if my laptop is currently plugged in so that I can start/pause CPU intensive tasks as necessary.

Better yet, a way to get notifications whenever there is a change to the plugged in state.

Comment: for crying out loud... I'm looking for a PROGRAMATIC way to detect this, this is a programming question, sheesh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`pmset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html):

> `-g` ps / batt displays status of batteries and UPSs.

Saying:

```
pmset -g ps
```

would tell you if the laptop is running on AC power or using battery power.

To translate into a condition, something like the following should work:

```
if [[ $(pmset -g ps | head -1) =~ "AC Power" ]]; then
  echo "power on!"
fi
```

Comment: awesome, thank you :)  I wonder if grepping for "AC Power" is consistent enough...

Comment: @cwolves I assume that it should be.

Comment: yeah, me too.  I'm just wondering if `!"Battery"` would be better.  Not that I can think of anything other than "AC Power" and "Battery" :)   ... I'm overthinking this ;)

Comment: Reverse-engineering `pmset` would tell you exactly how it is making that determination, so you don't have to parse its output. I'm not a Mac guy, but on Linux this kind of stuff is usually found in `/proc` or `/sys`.  Also, running [`dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) might show you right away.

Comment: @cwolves Fair enough :-)  After all, [it doesn't appear to be so simple](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/pmset/pmset.c).

Answer (score 4):

[`pmset(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) looks promising.  Specifically:

> **-g** ps / batt displays status of batteries and UPSs.

Looking through the [source code for `pmset`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-211/pmset/pmset.c), it seems that the key function you're looking for is [`IOPSGetProvidingPowerSourceType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/Reference/reference.html), which

> Indicates the power source the computer is currently drawing from.